# How do I scrape data from a tag belonging to the same label and the same class? BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have a tag with the same tag and the same name(property).
Here is my code

```
first_movie.find('p',{'class' : 'sort-num_votes-visible'})
```

Here is my output

```
<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">
<span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
<span data-value="978272" name="nv">978,272</span>
<span class="ghost">|</span> <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
<span data-value="858,373,000" name="nv">$858.37M</span>
</p>
```

I'm reaching span tag this code;

```
first_movie.find('span', {'name':'nv',"data-value": True})
```

978272 --> output

But i want reach the other value with named nv ($858.37M).
My code is only getting this value (978,272) because tags names is equal each other (name = nv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

Try using `find_all` and then grab the last element.

For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_sample = '''
<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">
<span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
<span data-value="978272" name="nv">978,272</span>
<span class="ghost">|</span> <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
<span data-value="858,373,000" name="nv">$858.37M</span>
</p>
'''

soup = (
    BeautifulSoup(html_sample, "lxml")
    .find_all("span", {'name':'nv',"data-value": True})
)
print(soup[-1].getText())
```

Output:

```
$858.37M
```

Answer (score -1):

If you reach for all spans in p tag, you can work with them like with list and use index to reach for last div.

```
movies = soup.find('p',{'class' : 'sort-num_votes-visible'})

my_movie = movies.findAll('span')

my_span = my_movie[3].text
```